# Disguise web folder as image file

Tags: html, web

This "screamer" has been floating around on the internet for a while disguised as an image file when in reality it's a web page with a flash object that plays a loud noise with a flashing image to scare you.  My question is how exactly was the creator of this screamer able to disguise it this way.

This link is here (WARNING: very loud):

http://akk.li/pics/anne.jpg

As you can see, the image is not an image at all. The link actually takes the visitor to the directory http://akk.li/pics/anne/jpg.  How is this done?

I have a website myself and I'm trying to replicate it out of curiosity. I am familiar with html, php and javascript, and I'm using the "cPanel Accelerated 2" web app on my web host's site.
[image: cPanel Accelerated 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the extension of a file doesn't matter. What counts is what mimetype you serve it as. You do need to tell the server to parse it as html or php (or whichever language you use)

You can have jpg files parsed as php with this in htaccess

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .jpg
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried messing with the MIME types with no luck. I think maybe my host might be preventing me from overriding the default jpg extension... oh well

Comment: You could also rewrite the url
I think `RewriteRule ^anne.jpg$ /yourdir/anne.php` might work.

Comment: Thanks but that just redirects the visitor and changes the url in their browser which isn't exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

The web server is responding with the content type of text/html, so your browser is interpreting the servers response as this. Their web server is literally just serving a HTML response. How to do the same depends on the language / framework you're using.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, for example, you can use this: `header('Content-type: text/html');`
I believe this causes the page, regardless of extension, to be interpreted as an HTML.

Comment: how would you implement that in this case?